# How to create a WP-CLI command with $_POST?

Tags: wp-cli

I would like to create a WP-CLI command for [WordPress Database Reset plugin](https://github.com/chrisberthe/wordpress-database-reset/).

In the [main function](https://github.com/chrisberthe/wordpress-database-reset/blob/master/wp-reset.php#L50) it uses $_POST for the options but when running the command in cli they will not exist.

How should go about creating the cli command?

I have seen the [commands cookbook](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/Commands-Cookbook).

```
function wp_reset_init() {
    global $wpdb, $current_user, $pagenow;

    // Grab the WordPress database tables
    $this->_wp_tables = $wpdb->tables();

    // Check for valid input - goes ahead and drops / resets tables
    if ( isset($_POST['wp-random-value'], $_POST['wp-reset-input']) && $_POST['wp-random-value'] == $_POST['wp-reset-input']
        && check_admin_referer('wp-nonce-submit', $this->_nonce) ) {

        require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

        // No tables were selected
        if ( ! isset($_POST['tables']) && empty($_POST['tables']) ) {
            wp_redirect( admin_url( $pagenow ) . '?page=wp-reset&reset=no-select' ); exit();
        }

        // Get current options
        $blog_title = get_option('blogname');
        $public = get_option('blog_public');

        $admin_user = get_user_by('login', 'admin');
        $user = ( ! $admin_user || ! user_can($admin_user->ID, 'update_core') ) ? $current_user : $admin_user;

        // Get the selected tables
        $tables = (isset($_POST['tables'])) ? array_flip($_POST['tables']) : array();

        // Compare the selected tables against the ones in the database
        $this->_tables = array_diff_key($this->_wp_tables, $tables);

        // Preserve the data from the tables that are unique
        if ( 0 < count($this->_tables) ) {
            $backup_tables = $this->_backup_tables($this->_tables);
        }

        // Grab the currently active plugins and theme
        if ( isset($_POST['wp-reset-check']) && 'true' == $_POST['wp-reset-check'] ) {
            $current_data['active-plugins'] = get_option( 'active_plugins' );
            $current_data['current-theme'] = get_option( 'current_theme' );
            $current_data['template'] = get_option( 'template' );
            $current_data['stylesheet'] = get_option( 'stylesheet' );
        }

        // Run through the database columns, drop all the tables and
        // install wp with previous settings
        if ( $db_tables = $wpdb->get_col("SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$wpdb->prefix}%'") ) {
            foreach ($db_tables as $db_table) {
                $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE {$db_table}");
            }
            $keys = wp_install($blog_title, $user->user_login, $user->user_email, $public);
            $this->_wp_update_user($user, $keys);
        }

        // Delete and replace tables with the backed up table data
        if ( ! empty( $backup_tables ) ) {
            foreach ($this->_tables as $table) {
                $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM " . $table);
            }
            $this->_backup_tables($backup_tables, 'reset');
        }

        if ( ! empty( $current_data ) ) {
            update_option( 'active_plugins', $current_data['active-plugins'] );
            if ( ! empty( $current_data['current-theme'] ) ) {
                update_option( 'current_theme', $current_data['current-theme'] );
            }
            update_option( 'template', $current_data['template'] );
            update_option( 'stylesheet', $current_data['stylesheet'] );
            wp_redirect( admin_url($pagenow) . '?page=wp-reset&reset=success' ); exit();
        }

        wp_redirect( admin_url() ); exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your current code.

Answer (score 6):

The main problem is that your `wp_reset_init()` method deals with too many things. It's looking at the `$_POST` request, it's performing database queries, and it's performing redirects.

You need to [separate your concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) so you end up with a new method which only performs the database reset, and which accepts parameters rather than using `$_POST` directly. You can then call this more tightly-focused method from your WP-CLI command (using the values from `$assoc_args`) and from your current `wp_reset_init()` method (using the values from `$_POST`).